# Uncaught ArgumentCountError: Too few arguments to function

Tags: php, class, pdo

I want to save the data with `$_POST` method to the database using PDO with PHP. I wrote the code, but it gave me an error. Is there anyone who can figure this out?

macex.php

```
function daireekle($daire_no,$dpass,$daire_statu,$daire_adi,$daire_soyadi){
    $sql ="insert into users (KULLANICIADI,SIFRE,TIPI,ADI,SOYADI) values ('$daire_no','$dpass','$daire_statu','$daire_adi','$daire_soyadi')";
    $insert =$this->connection->query($sql);
}
```

Blok.html

```
<?php
$sinif = new macex();
if ($_POST) {
    $daire_no = $_POST['daireno'];
    $daire_adi = $_POST['daireadi'];
    $daire_soyadi = $_POST['dairesoyadi'];
    $daire_statu = $_POST['statu'];
    $dpass = $_POST['dpass'];
    $sinif->daireekle('users', ['KULLANICIADI', 'SIFRE', 'TIPI', 'ADI', 'SOYADI'], [$daire_no, $dpass, $daire_statu, $daire_adi, $daire_soyadi]);
}
?>
```

Comment: So, firstly, to be clearly, `daireekle()` is a method from a class, right? Secondly, your function accepts 5 parameters and you are sending only 3: `'users', array, array`. In provided code you do not accept 'users' and first array. You accept only values of the 2nd array.

Comment: either you change the function `daireekle()` or you change the call to it. The way you call it now might be more flexible for future usage, _BUT_ it's open to sql injection anyway. So rather change that function to use prepared statements.

Comment: **Warning:** You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use parameterized [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of manually building your queries like that. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is a bit difficult to understand, in terms of structure, but you're definitely misusing `PDO` by injecting unsanitized `POST` data.

If I were to attempt to convert your sample into something workable, I would suggest the following amendments:

*(**Note**: Assuming `$this->connection->` is your PDO object)*

***Blok.html***
  *(not sure why you've called this **PHP** file `Blok.html`)*

```
<?php
$sinif = new macex();
if ($_POST) {
    $sinif->daireekle( $_POST );
}
?>
```

***macex.php***

```
function daireekle( $postArray ){

// Parameterised PDO will mostly prevent SQL Injection, but it's still best practice 
// to validate and sanitize your inputs, especially if they are coming from the user
$daire_no = $postArray ['daireno'];
$daire_adi = $postArray ['daireadi'];
$daire_soyadi = $postArray ['dairesoyadi'];
$daire_statu = $postArray ['statu'];
$dpass = $postArray ['dpass'];

// Define the query with positional params
$sql = 'INSERT INTO users (KULLANICIADI, SIFRE, TIPI, ADI, SOYADI) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)';

// Create an array of your params in the order they apply to the query
$paramsArray = array('$daire_no','$dpass','$daire_statu','$daire_adi','$daire_soyadi');

// Prepare the parameterised query
$query = $this->connection->prepare($sql);

// Execute the INSERT query with the parameters
$query->execute($paramsArray);

}
```

You could of course use different variations on the above, included named parameters, but it's conciser to explain as per the above.